# How Do I Select a `td` Element in a Row That Has a Checkbox That is Checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table that looks somethings like this:

```
<table>
  <tr class="row even">
    <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td class="name">foo</td>
    <td class="metric">22</td>
  </tr>

  ...etc
```

What I want to do is get an array of all `td.metric` only in rows that have the checkbox checked.  This didn't work out as expected:

```
var ticks = $.map($("tr td input:checked td.metric"), function(v,i){ return ... });
```

Comment: Have you tried removing all specifiers besides the td.metric?

Comment: yes, but that gets all rows regardless of the checkbox checked state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`:has`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector:

```
$('tr:has(input:checked) > .metric');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RqjFX/

Comment: Now that's what I call sexy :) (I know I know, I'm sad)